# Google Apps Script splice method oddness

Tags: google-apps-script, splice

splice seems to be creating a dynamic relationship between spliced in elements and the elements they were spliced from ... ???

Say I have an array
Array = [ [1 , 2 , 3] ]

I want to duplicate this column and change the last value of the new column to 4. I used:
nada = Array.splice(0,0,Array[0]);
Array[1][2] = 4;

However, this results in
Array = [ [ 1 , 2 , 4] , [ 1 , 2 , 4] ]

This is a stripped down example, in the actual problem I'm iterating through solutions adding possibilities at each step, so nested loops would get messy ...

Insights?? .. or: how do I duplicate a column in the middle of an array and change one of it's values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve `[[1, 2, 3]]` to `[[1, 2, 3, 4]]` usig Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- First, `Array` is an object. In this case, I would like to recommend renaming the variable `Array`.
- In the case of `array.splice(0, 0, array[0])`, `[1, 2, 3]` is inserted to the top element.
- And, at `array[1][2] = 4`, `3` of `[1, 2, 3]` is replaced with `4`. Also, in this case, both elements are changed with the pass-by-reference. By this, the result is `[ [ 1 , 2 , 4] , [ 1 , 2 , 4] ]`.

When these points are reflected in the script, how about the following modifications?

#### Modified scripts:

```js
// If you want to use array[0][3] = 4.
const array1 = [[1, 2, 3]];
array1[0][3] = 4;
console.log(array1); // [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]

// If you want to use splice.
const array2 = [[1, 2, 3]];
array2.forEach(row => row.splice(row.length, 0, 4));
console.log(array2); // [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]

// Another approach 1
const array3 = [[1, 2, 3]];
array3.forEach(row => row.push(4));
console.log(array3); // [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]

// Another approach 3
const array4 = [[1, 2, 3]];
const res = array4.map(row => [...row, 4]);
console.log(res); // [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]
```

- These scripts return the same result of `[ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]` from `[[1, 2, 3]]`.

#### Note:

- I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, for example, if you want to achieve `[[1, 2, 3]]` to `[[1, 2, 4]]` usig Google Apps Script, how about the following samples?

```js
  // If you want to use array[0][3] = 4.
  const array1 = [[1, 2, 3]];
  array1[0][2] = 4;
  console.log(array1); // [ [ 1, 2, 4 ] ]

  // If you want to use splice.
  const array2 = [[1, 2, 3]];
  array2.forEach(row => row[2] = 4);
  console.log(array2); // [ [ 1, 2, 4 ] ]
```

#### References:

- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> Actually, I want to achieve [ [ 1,2,3],[1,2,4]], but I think you've pointed me down the path with the "pass by reference" coment. How would I pass by value in array.splice(0, 0, array[0])

I understood that you wanted to achieve `[[1, 2, 3]]` to `[ [ 1,2,3],[1,2,4]]`. In this case, how about the following sample script?

```js
const array1 = [[1, 2, 3]];
array1.push(array1[0].slice());
array1[1][2] = 4;
console.log(array1); // [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 4 ] ]

const array2 = [[1, 2, 3]];
array2.push([...array2[0]]);
array2[1][2] = 4;
console.log(array2); // [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 4 ] ]

// If you want to use splice.
const array3 = [[1, 2, 3]];
array3.splice(array3.length, 0, [...array3[0]]); // array3.splice(array3.length, 0, array3[0].slice());
array3[1][2] = 4;
console.log(array3); // [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 4 ] ]

// If you want to use array.splice(0, 0, array[0]) 
const array4 = [[1, 2, 3]];
array4.splice(0, 0, [...array4[0]]); // or array4.splice(0, 0, array4[0].slice());
array4[1][2] = 4;
console.log(array4); // [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 4 ] ]
```

Comment: Actually, I want to achieve [ [ 1,2,3],[1,2,4]], but I think you've pointed me down the path with the "pass by reference" coment. How would I pass by value in array.splice(0, 0, array[0])

Comment: @JOD Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, I understood that you wanted to achieve `[[1, 2, 3]]` to `[ [ 1,2,3],[1,2,4]]`. So, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. In order to the pass-by-value of an array, [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) can be used.

Comment: Your english is great.

Comment: And that worked. I'll have to look up what the "..." construct does, but it's clearly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @JOD Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `...`, this is spread syntax. For example, in the case of `const array = [[1, 2, 3]];`, `[...array[0]]` is `[1, 2, 3]`. An array of the 1st element can be expanded each value. You can see more information on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).